# Add text subscript in kable column names in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to adapt one of my column names, "IC50", to be "IC<sub>50</sub>". However, it does not work in R shiny within the *kable* function. I created a toy example below:

I set UI to be

```
htmlOutput("summary")
```

Output is coded as:

```
output$summary <- renderText({
  names_spaced <- c(
    ' ', 'Slope', 'Slope1', 
    'Slope2',             
    'IC<sub>50</sub>', 'SE', 'Pval')
  
  model.dt <- data.frame(Model = c("A","B","C"),
                         Slope = 1:3,
                         Slope1 = 1:3,
                         Slope2 = 1:3,
                         IC50 = 1:3,
                         IC50.Std.Err = 1:3,
                         IC50.Pvalue = 1:3)
  
  model.dt %>%
    kable(col.names = names_spaced)
})
```

However, the display in the outcome Shiny app still shows what I have within the quotation mark. Also, neither "IC~50~" nor "IC^50^" work.

I am not familiar with how the kable function works within the htmloutput in Shiny. Are there any ways to code the subscript?

Thanks!!

Comment: Adding `escape = FALSE` works. `kable(col.names = names_spaced, escape = FALSE)`